# jQuery multiple selectors with window or document

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I know how to use multiple CSS selectors with jQuery, but how can I bind an event listener to multiple selectors when one of them is an object, the `document` or the `window` object for instance.

The following doesn't work :

```
$('html, body', document).scroll(function () {
    if(Screen.detectScroll() === 'down') {
        self.hide();
    } else {
        self.show();
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('html, body').add(document)`

Comment: @cookiemonster Yep, I actually just found that. Answer my question if you wish.

Comment: I'll let someone else. Go ahead if you'd like.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [Add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add selectors.

```
$('html, body').add(document).scroll(function () {
    if(Screen.detectScroll() === 'down') {
        self.hide();
    } else {
        self.show();
    }
});
```